# Scrapy passing custom values

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that works perfectly fine, but now I want to add another value to the item. The problem is the value `stamp` I need to pass is in `parse`. `stamp` value correlates to the link I pass to `get_details`, but `stamp` is on original page only. How can i modify code to add `stamp` value to every time I generate. Thank you

```
def parse(self, response):
    stamp = response.xpath("//div[@class='byline']/time/@datetime")

    for url in response.xpath("//h2[@class='post-title']/a/@href").extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details)

def get_details(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['title'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
        article['url'] = response.url
        yield article
```

Comment: I don't know if I correctly understand your question but if you need to pass some data to callback method you can use Scrapy [request.meta](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) attribute.

Comment: I grab all links I need using `//h2[@class='post-title']/a/@href` and then i get all data i need from the page. But `stamp` is only available on the main page. And every single link I grab has a `stamp`. How do I pass it to the item so it comes together.

Comment: Just add `request.meta['stamp'] = stamp` to you request in `parse` and in `get_details` you can get stamp value with `stamp = response.meta['stamp']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just pass the stamp data through the meta attribute of your request and then pull it out of the response object in your `get_details` method:

```
def parse(self, response):

    # !! As I don't know the actual page these xpaths are my best guesses and need adjustments
    for item in response.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'river-block')]"):
        url = item.xpath(".//h2[@class='post-title']/a/@href").extract()[0]
        stamp = item.xpath(".//time/@datetime").extract()
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details, meta={'stamp': stamp})

def get_details(self, response):
    article = ArticleItem()
    article['title'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
    article['url'] = response.url
    article['stamp'] = response.meta['stamp']
    yield article
```

Comment: that didn't work me. Firstly, it takes all `stamp` and passes them to get_details and secondly, it doesn't save them at all

Comment: it actually saves those stamps, but for every item it creates it saves all of the stamps to each item.

Comment: and it saves it in this format: `<Selector xpath="//div[@class='byline']/time/@datetime" data=u'2017-05-16 04:17:22'>` but I just need what's inside data.

Comment: i forgot to add .extract() at the end of `stamp`. It know saves data only. Still all stamps are assigned to every item

Comment: That's correct, extract() had been missing. I restructured the code so it could get the right stamp together with the URL, but the xpaths defintely need to be adjusted. Can help you with this, if you post the page's URL here.

Comment: i see what you did there, i'll edit path and it should work fine. i'll confirm your answer as soon as i finish

Comment: I'm trying to crawl TechCrunch. I modified the xcode path but for some reason it says that **Request url must be str or unicode, got list**. Here is my code:

`def parse(self, response):
        
    for item in response.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'river-block')]").extract():
            url = item.xpath(".//h2[@class='post-title']/a/@href").extract()
            stamp = item.xpath(".//time/@datetime").extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details, meta={'stamp': stamp})`

Comment: `extract` returns a list, even if there is only one url. So either do a `[0]` or a `"".join` on it. Adjusted my code accordingly.

Comment: for some reason this spider doesn't catch all items. It only takes first and finishes. Hasn't changed a code. two hours ago worked perfectly fine. Any idea what might have happened?

Comment: If the same code worked fine a few hours ago, your IP might be getting blocked as there are/were too many requests and/or too fast ... try going slower or through a different IP to confirm this.